# Composer error when trying to include multi level public personal repositories

Tags: composer-php

I'm splitting up some of my personal code to modularize and reuse it on different projects.
I've started using composer recently and have been using it for referencing these modules on my projects.

The following has worked for me so far:

```
First project composer.json

{
    "name": "mpf/apimodule",
    "version":"dev-main",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "APIModule\\":"classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

```
Second project composer.json

{
    "name": "mpf/crawler",
    "version":"dev-main",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "API\\": "classes/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:{User}/{Repo}.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2",
        "mpf/apimodule": "dev-main"
    }
}
```

Both composers are compiled and the project works as intended.

But when I try to add a third layer

```
Third project composer.json

{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "API\\": "classes/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:{User}/{Repo}.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "mpf/crawler": "dev-main"
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running the composer update command

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires mpf/crawler dev-main -> satisfiable by mpf/crawler[dev-main].
    - mpf/crawler dev-main requires mpf/apimodule dev-main -> could not be found in any 
version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

I've found a similar issue, but my repositories are all public and that was the problem for them.

I've tried running composer -vvv / composer diagnose, but couldn't find any useful information with the results.

Comment: This isn't really a Git issue, it's a composer dependency issue. I don't use composer so I don't know if [this article](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/debugging-composer-dependency-conflicts) is a good one, but it seems fairly thorough.

Comment: Please share more details. How should Composer find `mpf/apimodule`? That package is not available on packagist.org

Comment: @NicoHaase From what I understand, adding the repositories array includes the git urls into the composer's PATH, so it would look for the packages both in packagist.org and the repositories added (might be wrong).

Edit: Found the following line on composer's documentation that might clarify it in a better way:
"By default, only the Packagist.org repository is registered in Composer. You can add more repositories to your project by declaring them in composer.json."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description given in your question, you add repositories into *root* `composer.json` files. This works fine as long as you're using the root `composer.json` file. That *is* the project having *this* file.

Now while this works on each per-project basis, when you put the third (or fourth, fifth etc. ) `composer.json` file into the mix, or as you word it *"add a third layer"*, it stops working.

Technically it does not stop working, however Composer can not resolve that *inherited* repository any longer to resolve the *root* dependency:

> ```
> - Root composer.json requires mpf/crawler dev-main \
>     -> satisfiable by mpf/crawler[dev-main].
> - mpf/crawler dev-main requires mpf/apimodule dev-main \
>     -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
> ```

As honest as Composer is here, it may be puzzling in your situation. You've certainly already double-checked there is **no** typo and still though, Composer can not find **any** version.

That is because Composer uses the `composer.json#/repositories` configuration only from the *root* `composer.json` - that is the file itself. Let's visualize this a bit:

```
composer.json
vendor/mpf/crawler/composer.json
```

My educated guess is that, albeit you've added the repository for `mpf/crawler` to `composer.json` the repository for `mpf/apimodule` has not been added to it but only to `vendor/mpf/crawler/composer.json`.

The fix is easy, add *all* repositories your *root* project requires to resolve *all* dependencies to *that* projects configuration file (`composer.json` in the project you install the dependencies in).

If you think this through, it might become more clear why that is so:

The moment you install from `composer.json`, all repositories should be defined already as otherwise the outcome of the install will be a pure game of luck. Packages would be able to overwrite *your* repositories configuration and you would not be in control any longer.

My recommendations to continue your journey:

1. Add repositories inside your *root* `composer.json` file, to ensure your projects' configuration is complete. *(Goal: understanding *root* configuration, the project level)*
2. When working with this, consider if you want to have a *global* configuration of repositories. That is you can on the level of your computer user configure a list of repositories shared across projects (on that host). *(Goal: understanding *global* configuration, the level of your host, working with project**s**)*
3. Take a Safari-Tour on the different types of repositories Composer offers (compare [with the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)) as you may find even more in there (e.g. path repositories, another central .json file you can share etc. - there are quite some options). *(Goal: understanding of the different repository configuration types)*

---

[kuba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549728/kuba) points to an entry in the Composer FAQ for this topic *([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906210/367456))*:

- [Why can't Composer load repositories recursively? (Composer FAQ)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-cant-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md)

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely correct. Thanks for linking the documentation. Here's a line from it: 
"Repositories are only available to the root package and the repositories defined in your dependencies will not be loaded."

As my original idea was having an array of modules at my disposal without the need to add them all to a server manually or worrying about the packages needed at the bottom layer, for now I'll stop being lazy and host my packages on packagist, as there's currently no need for them to be private

Comment: thanks for commenting, honestly, this is all up to what you want to do. Composer just gives you the options and packagist is available for public use, so looks legit to me to publish them there, this is likely where you had them at the end anyway. To speed up locally, checkout the repositories configuration in the global configuration, the second point. It looks like you've made your decision on the 1. now. And it's not lazy, it's learning, if you like it the hard and dirty way, you can blame yourself, but why? Instead if you find a mistake, own it.

Comment: Hint: VCS git repositories you can configure directly from the file-system, just provide the absolute path to the project folder. So you can have packagist and locally you have the freshest of the packages as if you'd have already published them.