# Composer can't find sub-sub-package

Tags: composer-php, repo

For reasons too complicated to go into (but are valid) I have been forced to fork three repos and modify them to make some code work (prior to creating a fully working upgrade - it's complicated).

Anyway, regardless of why I need it, this is what I've got that isn't working...

Top level `package_a` in one git repo:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/wibble-3325967.git"
        }
    ]
```

This loads correctly, but in its composer.json it has this:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "github",
      "url": "git@github.com:myaccount/package_b.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "myaccount/package_b": "1.0.1"
  },
```

Which is the second repo I forked, `package_b`, and in its composer.json, we have

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "github",
      "url": "git@github.com:myaccount/package_c.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "myaccount/package_c": "^1",
  },
```

I have deleted `composer.lock` plus the code for `package_a` , and I'm running the command:

```
composer clearcache && composer update --prefer-source
```

But all I ever get is:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires myaccount/package_a =3.0.1 -> satisfiable by myaccount/package_a[3.0.1].
    - myaccount/package_a 3.0.1 requires myaccount/package_b 1.0.1 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

The tag `1.0.1` does exist. I know it's accessing `myaccount/package_b` because after a while it required me to set up a token in order to continue trying to access it (too many accesses).

I've tried a lot of different options over the last few hours, including (but not limited to) duplicating the repositories entries at the top level and referencing the master branch instead of a tag. It's not a stability issue because the package_a doesn't have dev, alpha or beta in their branch/tag names.

Comment: Please double-check with this existing Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74765807/367456 - _"could not be found in any version"_ was the flag for me here (and there).

Answer (score 2):

You have to define all repositories in your main `composer.json`.

Compare with the official explanation<sup>1</sup>:

> You may run into problems when using custom repositories because Composer does not load the repositories of your requirements, so you have to redefine those repositories in all your `composer.json` files.

One such problem you have in your question: The package is not found in any version.

And further:

> [...] you have to understand that the main use of custom VCS & package repositories is to temporarily try some things, or use a fork of a project until your pull request is merged, etc. You should not use them to keep track of private packages.

---

1. [Why can't Composer load repositories recursively?](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-cant-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md).